# Problem in finding key of Binary Search Tree in a Data Strucutre Project C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a user information text file. The users information are in this format : 
UserName#ConnectionDate#DisconnectionDate#TrafficUsage 
For example :
*arman#2019/1/7-17:14:8#2019/1/7-17:14:10#1234* 
Now the project is to make a Binary Search Tree when reading the text file and do some actions like delete a userinfo and etc..
My problem is which field should i took for key of BST ?

I know how to implement a BST and etc.. 
But in this case i don't know how to implement a userinfo to a node of BST ?

And of-course maybe other methods are better, But it has to implemented by a Binary Search Tree.

-edit-
There is more than 1 record for each user. 
Some reports that projects wants:
Count of each user that connect to the server.
the history of user connection in a period like 2018 to 2019.
print all users alphabetical.--

Is the tree loks like this ? :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfkgh.png)
Thanks alot.

Comment: The choice of key is dictated by the use case(s). If you want to be able to delete user info, the input to that is probably going to be the user name of the record to delete, so you'll need to use user name as the key.

Comment: Probably need more information, like is there more than one record per user? If so, the records are probably unique on UserName and ConnectionDate so you could use that as a key.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for your answer. the question has edited. can you explain more how to use username as the key ? I mean how to search by the username in BST ? thanks

Comment: @MikeS Thanks for your answer. the question has edited. Can you explain more how to do that in BST ? thanks

Comment: The question is too broad. What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I can do this project by a simple loop that reads each line, and do the all things...But my question is how to implement this by the Binary Search Tree ? which field should i use as a key ?

Comment: If you need to find users in alphabetical order the key should probably be the user name.

Comment: @Lee Thanks for your answer. how i use the username as a key ? What the tree looks like?

Comment: How the tree looks depends on your input data. The nodes will be sorted based on the username.

Comment: @Lee Based on my input data : Username#ConnectionDate#DisconnectionDate#TrafficUsage. and we use Username as the key.Is the tree looks like this ? : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfkgh.png

Comment: Yes that would be valid, although the exact structure depends on the insert order.

Comment: @Lee Thanks alot. But what do you mean "insert order" ? for example if i add a record which the username is user3, i will insert the record to the left of first child of 2nd right node of root.Is that it ?

Comment: I mean that inserting `user1, user2, user3` in that order will result in a different BST to inserting `user2, user1, user3`. In the first case, `user1` will be the root but in the second case `user2` will be the root. That's assuming you're implementing a non-balancing BST.

Comment: @Lee Wow! Thanks alot. It really helped! and the last question(:D) is it better to have a balancing BST? the search speed will be more ?

Comment: Balanced trees like AVL or red-black trees have a better worst-case complexity than one which is not self-balancing since these can degenerate into linked lists in the worst case. On the other hand, unbalanced trees are simpler to implement so are usually introduced first since they are easier to understand. If this is homework then I suggest you implement the BST you've been shown so far.

Comment: @Lee actually this is the end-of-semester project. We've read AVL Trees, Threaded Trees. and the project has extra score if we implement this by AVL or Threaded tree.Is it worth if i implement by these or should i take the simple BST tree ?

Comment: That's up to you depending on how comfortable you are with the various implementations. I would recommend implementing a self-balancing tree if you have time and are confident enough. Red-black trees are fairly common (e.g. the .net `SortedSet<T>` type). If you're not sure, I suggest you define a suitable interface for your tree, implement it using a basic non-balacing BST and then replace it with a self-balancing implementation once you have fulfilled the requirements.

Comment: @Lee Thank you very much for your help. :x